# Fire GTM dataayer variable on specific history change

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, react-gtm-module

I am using [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module) in my react project to add Google Tag Manager in my project. As of now i was firing the dataLayer variable  whereever required by the following code

```
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
          window.dataLayer.push({
          Car_NewUser_Create: 'Yes'
 })
```

but now there is a special case where i need to fire this same varaible "Car_NewUser_Create" when we go from "/simulcao" route to "/pacotes" route.

There is a configuration in GTM for history triger change that detects every change in history route, but for this specfic route change i need to pass this variable and I am not able to find any source on how to achieve it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use two undocumented variables populated on a history change event, i.e., `gtm.oldUrl` and `gtm.newUrl`.

This is an example of what GTM will push to the dataLayer when the history change event is enabled and triggered:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "gtm.historyChange",
  gtm.historyChangeSource: "pushState",
  gtm.oldUrlFragment: "",
  gtm.newUrlFragment: "",
  gtm.oldHistoryState: "",
  gtm.newHistoryState: {key: "", state: ""},
  gtm.oldUrl: "https://example.com/old-url",
  gtm.newUrl: "https://example.com/new-url",
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 0000
})
```

For some reason, the variables are undocumented in the [variable docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGzZE.png) and unavailable as built-in variables to be enabled.

Simply configure two new [dataLayer variables](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362?hl=en#data_layer) to capture them. Once that's out of the way, you can use them in any logic you need to apply in GTM.

In your case, set up a tag to `dataLayer.push({ Car_NewUser_Create: 'Yes' })` with a history change trigger for `Some History Changes` with two rules:

1. `gtm.oldUrl` equals `https://example.com/old-url`
2. `gtm.newUrl` equals `https://example.com/new-url`

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGzZE.png).